# How to activate my progressbar without setting setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to do is make the `porgressbar` run if i click the link to progress bar and then redirect to `Profile form` after the progressbar reach 100%. I'm making a single page website using javascript show and hide form.

My problem is when the program starts the progressbar starts too even though I am in the `Home form` and it will auto redirect to Profile form.

current output:

http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/25/

```
var value = 0, progress;

//progress bar script
function progressBar() {
    progress = setInterval(function () {
        var $bar = $('.bar');
        if (value >= 100) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
            // go to profile after progress bar reaches 100%
            $(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
        } else {
            value += 10;
            $bar.width(value * 4);
        }
        $bar.text(value + "%");
    }, 800);
};
```

Comment: Have you thought about using AngularJs as a framework for your single-page website?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem. it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are calling progressBar function on $(document).ready callback even though the starting page is not the progress bar page. So the function does what is supposed to do, irrespective of whether or not the progress bar is actually shown or not.

Removing that should make the code work as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/27/

```
// vars 
var value = 0, progress;

//progress bar script
function progressBar() {
    progress = setInterval(function () {
        var $bar = $('.bar');
        if (value >= 100) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
            // go to profile after progress bar reaches 100%
            $(".show-page[data-page=Profile]").trigger("click");
        } else {
            value += 10;
            $bar.width(value * 4);
        }
        $bar.text(value + "%");
    }, 800);
};
//for my show and hide form script
$(document).ready(function () {
    //progressBar();
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined" && sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
        var pageToShow = sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
        $('.page').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
    };
    $('.show-page').click(function () {
        var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');
        if (pageToShow == "progBar") {
            // reset progress var
            value = 0;
            $('.bar').width(0);
            $('.progress').addClass('active');
            progressBar();
        } else {
            clearInterval(progress);
        };
        $('.page').addClass('hide');
        $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
        };
    });
    $('.modal-btn').click(function () {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```